# Centripetal force on electron moving through curved wire

Tags: electric-current, centripetal-force

Suppose we have a curved ohmic conductor in the form of a circular arc with some thickness say $d$. Now, say we apply a potential difference across the two ends of the conductor. The electrons will start moving through the conductor as a result of the potential difference supplied. However, to move in the curved circular path, we must exert some type of centripetal force on the electron. My question is what exactly produces this centripetal force and how exactly is the electron made to curve through the conductor?

Comment: @Dale I had previously gone through that but I don't understand it very well so I asked it in a rephrased manner.

Comment: When you don't understand an existing answer, then you need to write your question to specifically link to the existing question and explain what more you are looking for. What **specifically** is insufficient about the previous question and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same as absmall ball going through a curved tube, the wall provide the force, with e the wall have a slight negative charge to guide the e. But also the velocity is very small, so the force needed is small.